# What are the iOS Device Handle Requirements for Azure SendDirectNotificationAsync?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, device, handle

I am attempting to use SendDirectNotificationAsync to send notifications to unregistered iOS devices that obtain and update their 66 character device handle on each initialization to make sure it current. However, the outcome of the push from the hub reports "Device handle is invalid. It is either null or empty or has invalid value." I know that a handle is being entered into the method, so only being invalid is the error. A example of the handle is:

`<70ff27b5b101103fe462613da74c2f073c99479760db3e1c848b239e3a6b7553>`

Base on research, I read that the "<" & ">" should be excluded and the length should be 64 characters. I have tried both variations with the same results. What else is needed to make the handle valid?

Answer (score 0):

What I discover that there is an overload of SendDirectNotificationAsync for each platform based on the notification parameter class, e.g. WindowsNotification, AppleNotification or FcmNotification.

For APNS, the device handle is without spaces in it or <> at the ends.